# Returning string array to the method and print returned array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I return a `string[]` from a method:

```
public String[] demo
{
  String[] xs = new String {"a","b","c","d"};
  String[] ret = new String[4];
  ret[0]=xs[0];
  ret[1]=xs[1];
  ret[2]=xs[2];
  ret[3]=xs[3];

  retrun ret;
}
```

Is this right, because I tried it and it didn't work. How can I print this returned string array in main method.

Comment: can you show us how you tried printing in your main ?

Comment: "*because i tried it n it dint work*" => What did not work? You *are* returning an array from that method.

Comment: I've downvoted you because there is no evidence of prior research on your part. What have *you* tried?

Comment: hey listen i did mistake by writing retrun instead of return..

Answer (score 9):

Your code won't compile. It suffers from many problems (including syntax problems).

You have syntax errors - `retrun` should be `return`.

After `demo` you should have parenthesis (empty if you don't need parameters)

Plus,  `String[] xs = new String {"a","b","c","d"};`

should be:

`String[] xs = new String[] {"a","b","c","d"};`

Your code should look something like this:

```
public String[] demo()  //Added ()
{
     String[] xs = new String[] {"a","b","c","d"}; //added []
     String[] ret = new String[4];
     ret[0]=xs[0];
     ret[1]=xs[1];
     ret[2]=xs[2];
     ret[3]=xs[3];
     return ret;
}
```

Put it together:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    String[] res = demo();
    for(String str : res)
        System.out.println(str);  //Will print the strings in the array that
}                                 //was returned from the method demo()


public static String[] demo() //for the sake of example, I made it static.
{
     String[] xs = new String[] {"a","b","c","d"};
     String[] ret = new String[4];
     ret[0]=xs[0];
     ret[1]=xs[1];
     ret[2]=xs[2];
     ret[3]=xs[3];
     return ret;
 }
```

Comment: hey i did write "return"..cant u see??

Comment: Or `String[] xs = {"a","b","c","d"};`

Comment: @Hitman You didn't. For a brief period I had edited your question to spell `return` correctly, then I thought better of it.

Comment: sorry sorry..ok but it doesnt work if i write "return" also

Comment: @Hitman you wrote `retrun`, someone edited it to be `return`

Comment: but i did write return and then main method..and then compiled it..but its showing error like "can not find symbol" pointing "return ret".

Comment: @Hitman See: http://ideone.com/lnqTba

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//... in main
String [] strArr = demo();
for ( int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(strArr[i]);
}

//... demo method
public static String[] demo()
{
    String[] xs = new String [] {"a","b","c","d"};
    return xs;
}
```

Comment: `demo` isn't static, so this is not going to work